# How to find orthogonal vector to an arbitrary 3 dimentional vector

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, vectors

Given a vector $\begin{bmatrix}a\\b\\c\end{bmatrix}$ what is a simple solution to find any vector perpendicular to it?

Comment: In numerical calculations, approaches like "swap the largest and smallest components in magnitude, negating the largest one in magnitude, then orthogonalize (one step of Gram-Schmidt)", can be used.

Answer (score 1):

Most of the times you can use $\begin{bmatrix}b+c\\c-a\\-a-b\end{bmatrix}$ vector. But it is zero sometimes.

Here is the verification: $\begin{bmatrix}a\\b\\c\end{bmatrix} . \begin{bmatrix}b+c\\c-a\\-a-b\end{bmatrix} = a(b+c) + b(c-a)+c(-a-b)=0$

The third orthogonal vector is found by taking a cross product of initial and derived vector.

Any linear combination of these two derived vectors are orthogonal to original one as well.

Comment: Nice one. You should just emphasize that it's not unique.

Comment: as @dan-uznanski pointed, in another answer, this example doesn't work for some particular values.

Comment: And since (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hairy_ball_theorem) `There is no single continuous function that can generate a vector in R3 that is orthogonal to a given one for all vector inputs.` so it seems it is impossible to construct one _elegant_ universal solution.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a (non zero) $2$-dimensional vector **$\begin{bmatrix}a\\b\end{bmatrix}$**, the orthogonal vectors of it are the **$\lambda \begin{bmatrix}-b\\a\end{bmatrix}$** where $\lambda \in \mathbf{R}$.

So if you have a (non zero) $3$ dimensional vector **$\begin{bmatrix}a\\b\\c\end{bmatrix}$** you have easily a lot of orthogonal vectors : 
 $\lambda \begin{bmatrix}-b\\a\\0\end{bmatrix} + \mu\begin{bmatrix}0\\-c\\b\end{bmatrix}+ \nu \begin{bmatrix}-c\\0\\a\end{bmatrix} $
It is possible to check you generate all the orthogonal vectors to $\begin{bmatrix}a\\b\\c\end{bmatrix}$ like this (in reality, you just need two of them, but which ones you choose depends on the eventual annulations of $a$,$b$,$c$).

Comment: There are some trivial terms that might appear in my sum ; still you get every time all the othogonal vectors. If a=0, b=0, c=1 you have all the orthogonal vectors by choosing $\lambda$ = 0 and $\mu, \nu$ varying in $\mathbf{R}$ (so you don't need $\lambda$ in this case). If it was a=1, b=0, c=0, it is $\mu$ that is not needed.

Comment: This trio of vectors is actually of rank 2 (consider $\lambda=c$, $\mu = a$, and $\nu = -b$), so you need to take care that your parameters aren't part of the kernel.